# Using breakpoints in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using the debugger to pause execution of my program at any time and view the state of the running code, so I set breakpoints before running my executable so that I can stop at known points and view the values of variables in my source code.

[image: Set breakpoint and check the step over]

After I viewed my code, it comes to one new screen. Here I press "step over" button means it come to view the next line, if I press "Continue program execution" button means then it skipped the step by step execution and comes to execution part. Image shown below.

[image: New screen shows Assembly Language]

My doubt is, why the compiler come here after viewed my code? How to analyse this assembly language coding and what is the purpose of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pause execution or a breakpoint is triggered, the debug area opens, displaying the values of variables and registers plus the debug console. You can use the buttons at the right end of the debug area toolbar to display both the **variables** and **console** panes or to hide either one.

The **variables pane** displays variables and registers. You specify which items to display using the pop-up menu in the top-left corner of the variables pane:

1. Auto displays only the variables you’re most likely to be interested
   in, given the current context.
2. Local displays local variables.
3. All displays all variables and registers.

Use the search field to filter the items displayed in the variables pane.

The **console pane** displays program output and lets you enter commands to the debugger tool. You specify the type of output the console displays with the pop-up menu in the top-left corner of the console pane:

1. All Output displays target and debugger output.
2. Debugger Output displays debugger output only.
3. Target Output displays target output only.

Use these to understand what is happening at break points.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code casted exception and goes back to [UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] method . This method is in the compiled program and it is binary now so you won't see the source code and the assembly language is presented instead.

It is possible that [UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] has exception handling code.